# How to resize an img depends on the resolution?

Tags: jquery, css, resize, image, resolution

I have an img of 200px by 200px. I have a container for the img. The container size is 100%x100%. Basically the size of the container is depends on the window size. What I would like to achieve is if the screen size is gets smaller than 200px it should resize the img and make it smaller. I also would like to keep the ratio of the img. it should get smaller from height and width. is there a ready code for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

to your CSS (perhaps being more specific with your selector) and make sure your container has `position: relative` specified.

You probably want to ensure that the width of the container doesn't exceed the width of your image, as it will start to become pixelated. If that's not an issue, you can replace `max-width` with just `width` above. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/74HZ3/).

Comment: I second this. If you really need to get nitty-gritty you could always add a css media query for the 200px width, so that this only goes into effect once you reach that resolution: 

`@media all and (max-width: 200px) { img {max-width:100%;} }`

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width OR the height of the image to 100% using CSS. If you specify only one of these values, the other will be computed such as to retain the aspect ration of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing an image is not a good option as it degrades your website overall performance, it causes more time to render the page and it engulfs your user's RAM.

Comment: While I agree that it should be avoided on static image like icons if possible, resizing an image on the browser is perfectly acceptable in this case. Why else would we have powerful browsers if not to use their capabilities?

Comment: hi friend agree, just read about this http://www.rackaid.com/resources/fix-slow-sites/